# allowing modelform submission where model has required field by passing instance class based views Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have an edit form style  I used to use where allowing the user to submit a form was done by telling the form it is editing an instance, not making a new pk:

```
edit_form = PrivateProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile)
```

The app in question has a model with a required, unique field which should be (url):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    url         = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    title        = models.CharField
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

in the class based views, several attempts at passing the form instance=article fail, albeit silently, with my most recent failing being trying `form.instance = article_in_question`

view post:

```
 class ArticleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model           = Article
    form_class      = EditArticleForm
    template_name   = 'index/edit_article.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = Tag.objects.all() 
        return context

    def add_tags(self, article, tags_to_add):
        for tag in tags_to_add:
            article.tags.add(tag)

    def form_invalid(self, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(**kwargs))

    def post(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        article_in_question = Article.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        print article_in_question
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form_name = 'form'
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            tags_chosen = request.POST.getlist('selected_tags')
            form.instance = article_in_question
            article = form.save(commit=False)
            article.save()
            self.add_tags(article, tags_chosen)
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(**{form_name: form})
```

Tag and Article are separate models so I could not find a way to integrate them easily into one form yet. Adding tags in the view is fine and works on creating articles, so I want to just allow submissions of this pre-populated form without it trying to make a new model (which fails due to the unique requirement).

My current edit form and the original form for comparison:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('url', 'title', 'user')

    url     = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'required'}),
                  max_length=256, label='URL', required=True)    
    title   = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "I'll grab the page's title"}),
                  max_length=256, label='Title', required=False)
    user    = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput()) 

    def clean(self):
        try:
            title = self.cleaned_data['title']
            url   = self.cleaned_data['url']
            title = process_title(url)
            self.cleaned_data['title'] = title
        except:
            pass
        username = self.cleaned_data['user'] 
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        self.cleaned_data['user'] = user
        super(ArticleForm, self).clean()
        return self.cleaned_data


class EditArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    url     = forms.CharField(required=False)
    title   = forms.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('url', 'title')
```

I call the form the same as when creating objects, and in the view, `article_in_question` comes out as a real article. If you're curious the template looks as follows (same form that works on creating object):

```
<form id="article_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|bootstrap }}
    {% for tag in tags %}
        <div style="display:inline-block;" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="selected_tags" id="option{{tag.id}}" value={{tag.name}} />
            <label for="option{{tag.id}}">{{tag.name}}</label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit article"/>
```

after seeing in the shell:

```
In [5]: v = ArticleUpdateView()

In [8]: v.form_class
Out[8]: index.forms.EditArticleForm

In [14]: a = Article.objects.create(url='fake.com', title="fake")

In [15]: a
Out[15]: <Article: fake>

In [19]: form =v.form_class(instance=a)

In [20]: form
Out[20]: <EditArticleForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(url;title)>
```

I'm very surprised that:

```
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form_class.instance = article_in_question
    print form_class.instance
    form_name = 'form'
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
```

did not work. The printing of `form_class.instance` showed that the appropriate article is attached to that form class.

How can I tell the form that it is working on an instance in these class based views?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. If anyone else learning class views Django wants to learn this, notice `form = self.get_form(form_class)` is doing something internally that overwrites `instance` to `None`. The solution was:

```
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form_name = 'form'
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    form.instance = article_in_question
```

The way to see what these tricky class views do is going into ipython and grabbing one like

```
In [22]: from index.views import ArticleUpdateView

In [23]: v = ArticleUpdateView()
```

then playing with its items directly:

```
In [24]: v.
v.add_tags                 v.get_template_names
v.as_view                  v.http_method_names
v.content_type             v.http_method_not_allowed
v.context_object_name      v.initial
v.dispatch                 v.model
...etc...
```

this has proven much more effective than reading the docs for hours; while very thorough, they seem to lack practical examples in many cases